# How is Uniswap Liquidity added?

Tags: uniswap

I bet this is a simple answer, but I'm just unable to fully understand.

Uniswap has liquidity. It can be added. But what function does it uses? the `Transfer()` one from the contract?

I'm trying to find a way to track if someone adds liquidity to the pool, through the contract itself.

If anyone has knowledge about this I would appreciate, even if the answer isn't extremely detailed, I can still do more researches afterwards. Thank you.

Comment: this goes in uniswap v2 perifery ditectory, the addLiquidity function

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for this function: https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L61

> I'm trying to find a way to track if someone adds liquidity to the pool, through the contract itself.

`addLiquidity` calls this function:

https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/4dd59067c76dea4a0e8e4bfdda41877a6b16dedc/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol#L45

which should return this event:
https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol#L24

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm going to dive into that.

What I am a bit confused about is the link between my contract and Uniswap one. If my tokens are send to the Liquidity, it has to call a function from my contract first, so it receives the tokens right? If that's the case then I can track the tokens being sent from my own contract, in a simple way